# replace textstring with window.location url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this link in a webpage

WHATSAPP

What i want to do is insert the "window.location" full url where it says "landingpageurl" on that link.

How to do it with jquery or js?

Answer (score 1):

Since the ID of that text block is `#text-block`, you can utilise this like so:

```
document.getElementById("text-block").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text-block").innerHTML.replace("landingpageurl", window.location);
```

Demonstration:

```js
document.getElementById("text-block").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text-block").innerHTML.replace("landingpageurl", window.location);
```

```html
<p id="text-block">landingpageurl</p>
```

This says `stacksnippets.net` because that's where the snippets are executed. See [here](https://stacksnippets.net) for more information.

Comment: I need to edit the href attribute of the link and url encode the window.location, how?

Comment: <a id="linktowhatsapp" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=1157357051&amp;text=Quiero%20consultar%20por%20una%20cotizaci%C3%B3n%20de%20materiales%20de%20construci%C3%B3n%20en%20seco.%20El%20c%C3%B3digo%20del%20anuncio%20de%20Facebook%20d%C3%B3nde%20los%20vi%20fue:%20landingpageurl">WHATSAPP</a> this is the url

Comment: I don't understand, please explain @sebas?

Comment: <a id="linktowhatsapp" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=1157357051&amp;text=Quiero%20consultar%20por%20una%20cotizaci%C3%B3n%20de%20materiales%20de%20construci%C3%B3n%20en%20seco.%20El%20c%C3%B3digo%20del%20anuncio%20de%20Facebook%20d%C3%B3nde%20los%20vi%20fue:%20landingpageurl">WHATSAPP</a>

At the end of that href u can read "landingpageurl" what im trying to do is replace that string of text with the full url where the link is at (window.location) and encode that url so it can be part of that link